# Does hostgator accept ssl certificate into their starting shared hosting plan called "Hatching Plan"?

Tags: ssl

I bought a ssl certificate with their starting shared hosting plan called "Hatching Plan" on hostgator.com. When I just queried them I didn't got appropriate answers. So I withdrew the amount of SSL. Now I want to install the ssl plan again what can I do. What should be done to get green verification bar of extended ssl and installing?

Comment: Contact their customer service for help.

Comment: This is something you need to ask with their customer service

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the answer HostGator don't allow their users installing private ssl in Hatching plan. But in baby plan, they give the ability to host multiple domains and installing private ssl.